# Mixing audio on android with Jmusic

Tags: java, android, audio, mixing

I have been working on a music app for android devices for the past few months. I have written a considerable amount of code so far. However, I have been stuck for almost a month on the mixing part of the code. Since Android does not offer a way to mix audio (merge sounds into one file so that they play at the same time) I decided to add the [Jmusic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMusic) library to the project and use it to manipulate `audio` files. Unfortunately, every time I try to read an audio file from the `sdcard`, the app crashes. I have been looking for resource online to solve this problem, but I can't find a good one. I am thinking that maybe `Android` does not support the use of other `libraries`. Can any of you guys suggest an alternative solution if that's the case. An example `code` (with explanation) using `Java` would be greatly appreciated. What I am mainly doing is declaring a `float array` (data) and reading the audio file as such

```
     data = Read.Audio("string that holds the path of the file on the sd card");
```

Comment: Can you include a backtrace or specific details on what is crashing?  In general Android should allow 3rd-party Java libraries just fine, but some 3rd party libraries might rely on Java platform features that Android does not provide, and that could cause problems for a specific library.

Comment: What type of audio file are you trying to open. Have you tried performing a simple jmusic function just to see if the library works?

Answer (score 0):

what i think is android doesn't support javaSE environment..after the compilation process
Android produces dalvik code while java has it's byte code both of them being significantly different.